# Apply client_max_body_size to specific route in named location

Tags: node.js, nginx

I have the following: `nginx.conf` file:

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  server_name mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.com;

  server_tokens off;

  ssl_certificate /etc/certificates/mywebsite.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/certificates/mywebsite.com/privkey.pem;

  ssl_buffer_size 8k;

  ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam-2048.pem;

  ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

  ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;

  ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
  ssl_session_tickets off;

  ssl_stapling on;
  ssl_stapling_verify on;
  resolver 8.8.8.8;

  location / {
    client_max_body_size 10M;
    try_files $uri @nodejs;
  }

  location @nodejs {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
    add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade" always;
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src * data: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'" always;
    # enable strict transport security only if you understand the implications
    # add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;
  }

  root /var/www/html;
  # index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
}
```

which allows me to upload an image through the following `Node.js` endpoint (using: `HTTPS/443`):

```
https://www.mywebsite.com/api/photo/upload
```

It works just well for images up to: `10MB`.

That's because this config: `client_max_body_size 10M;`.

**What I need:** Apply the `10MB` limit just to that route: `/api/photo/upload` but not to others like: `/api/echo`. Notice that these routes are in named location: `@nodejs`.